# creating duplicate dictionary as column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, duplicates

dataframe has some duplicate values. There are two cases of duplicates

1. same ID showing up in the same category twice
2. same ID showing up in two different categories

As a rule, there should be a 1-1 mapping from ID to category.

I need to investigate the issues, and would like to create a new dataframe where my ID column has no duplicate values, but I have a second column that is a dictionary. The keys of the dictionary are the categories where ID is mapped to, and the value is the count. For instance, in case 1 there is a 1 element dictionary with value of 2, under case 2 there is a 2 element dictionary with each key having value of 1.

Below is an example of the dataframe `df`.

```
ID          Category
1001          cat1
1002          cat1
1002          cat1
1003          cat1
1003          cat2
1004          cat2
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the most efficient solution but works:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def list_to_dict(x):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for key in x:
        d[key]  += 1
    return dict(d)

d = {"ID": pd.Series([1001,1002,1002,1003,1003,1004]), "Category": pd.Series(['cat1','cat1','cat1','cat1','cat2','cat2'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.groupby('ID')['Category'].apply(list).apply(list_to_dict)
```

The output is:

```
ID
1001                {u'cat1': 1}
1002                {u'cat1': 2}
1003    {u'cat1': 1, u'cat2': 1}
1004                {u'cat2': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy - use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and apply lambda function with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html).

For `dict` column is used trick - create first `dict` in lists and then select each list by `str[0]`.

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')['Category']
        .apply(lambda x: [x.value_counts().to_dict()])
        .str[0]
        .reset_index()
print (df1)
     ID                Category
0  1001             {'cat1': 1}
1  1002             {'cat1': 2}
2  1003  {'cat1': 1, 'cat2': 1}
3  1004             {'cat2': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
from collections import Counter
df2 = df.groupby(["ID"])["Category"].apply(lambda x : Counter(list(x)))
```

Test:

```
df2.loc[1002]["cat1"]
df2.loc[1003]["cat1"]
```

Result:

```
2.0
1.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot create dict column this way - or uses some oldier version of pandas where is it possible. In version `0.20.3` it return new `Series` with `MultiIndex`